# FreeSwitch current calls migration

Tags: voip, high-availability, freeswitch

I installed FreeSwitch cluster according to official manual - https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Freeswitch_HA

And it works, when I power off first node current calls successfully move to second node and voice disappears only for 3 second.

The problem is when I power on first node, server starts FreeSwitch, and FreeSwitch during start up clears calls in database and of cause I can't move current calls back again to first node.

Can I move current calls between servers without interruption again? Thank you.

Comment: you need to ask this at freeswitch-users mailing list. Or dig in the sources and fix the problem yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem:

When first node comes online just restart the second node. So all current calls successfully move to first node.

Answer (score 0):

When FreeSWITCH starting it clear calls info from database. But data in DB are renewed at any call state change. You can write simple Lua script, which calls REINVITE's on each active call on secondary FreeSWITCH after primary starts. After this only one way to return calls from second node to first: fence (eg, with kill -9) freeswitch on second node and do `sofia recover` on first node to recover calls. At the same time, voice in call will disappeared for 3 second again. But why you don't want left secondary freeswitch to service calls? Or primary freeswitch call `sofia recover` at start? Or heartbeat returns main IP to first node automaticaly? If yes, you can migrate to corosync and simply increase stickness of resources. After this, active ip will stay on secondary node.